# PHP file downloaded instead of running

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script on my local server. The PHP script outputs xml. When I run this script from the command line, it functions correctly. However, when I run it from a web browser, the php file is downloaded in its entirety, rather than providing the xml output

I believe this is apache related. Can anyone give any pointers?

Comment: Is php running on your server? Is the file extension .php?

Comment: @thanks BigScar - file extension is .php

Comment: Easiest way to test if php is working on your server is to create a file in your www/ (or whatever directory you are using for public files), lets call it test.php, containing <? phpinfo(); ?>. Next, direct your browser to yourdomain/test.php and see if it works. If you don't get a nice pretty page with your PHP configuration, then your apache server doesn't have php running.

Comment: Ah. I am using Github Pages to host my site. I think this may be the issue. It appears it will not execute php, or any code

Comment: Thanks @frost287. I tried that - the file appears for download. Github pages wont work for this project it seems...